# python convert string to bytes error: ValueError: bytes too long

Tags: python, byte, structure, ctypes

I have this definition of Structure class with cytpes, which will be sent over socket:

```
import ctypes

class MyStructure(Structure):
      _pack_ = 1
      _fields_ = [("field1", c_int),
                 ("field2", c_longlong),
                 ("data", c_char * 1000)]
```

And the following code:

```
st = MyStructure()
strlist = str([i % 256 in range(1000)]) // 0,1,2,3,...
st.data = str.encode(strlist) // exception
```

Last line raises an exception:

> ValueError: bytes too long (3000, maximum length 1000)

Pass partial string will solve it but i don't understand the reason for the error:

```
st.data = str.encode(strlist)[:1000] // OK
```

Also, i'd like to know which conversion is the most straight-forward to do into a large 'bytes' type variable such as `st.data` (don't want to assign one by one)?

Comment: If you `print(strlist)` you'll see why... you're getting the string representation of a list containing integers - nothing to do with bytes... Can you not just make bytes directly? eg: `bytes(n % 256 for n in range(1000))` ?

Comment: i tried that, but got value of: b""

Comment: Really? If you literally copy and paste the above - you get an empty byte string?

Comment: yes. the variable is pre-defined as ctype structure (c_char * 1000)

Comment: I don't see how that relates to the code given in the comment to produce the byte string?

Comment: as is it works. the issue probably related to ctypes

Answer (score 0):

As Jon Clements mentioned in the first comment, converting string list to int turned any int value into three characters - the value, comma and space. For example, converting this int list `intlist = [5, ]` into string list `strlist = str(intlist)` will produde `len(strlist)` as 3!

A different way to insert data into the 'bytes' type could be:

```
st.data = b''
 for i in range(1000):
    st.data += (i % 256).to_bytes(1, "little")
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a byte string instead of a Unicode string:

```
from ctypes import *

class MyStructure(Structure):
      _pack_ = 1
      _fields_ = [("field1", c_int),
                 ("field2", c_longlong),
                 ("data", c_char * 1000)]

st = MyStructure()
st.data = bytes([i % 256 for i in range(1000)])
```